# List of 2 letters 2 numbers?

Tags: python, string, list, int

I'm looking for a list of 2 letters and then 2 numbers.  Something like:

```
aa00
aa01
aa02
aa03
aa04
ect.
```

I am using this for a Python program that picks a random 4 digit number, a random 4 letter string, and a random 2 letter 2 number string.

I tried combining half of the first two, but it said that it could not add `'int' and 'str' objects`.  I couldn't convert the numbers to a `string`, because they are used for a mathematical equation later in the program.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far so we can help you make it work.

Comment: Don't delete question once answer(s) have been posted unless you've a very compelling reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the number into a string *just for the concatenation*:

```
result = letters + str(number)
```

But if you want to have the numbers 0 through to 9 work too you probably want to zero-pad the number. You could use string formatting here, using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
result = '{}{:02d}'.format(letters, number)
```

Both approaches leave the `number` variable *untouched*; it is still referencing a number.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you

**Code 1 :**

```
import random as rn

num = ''
stg = ''

for i in range(2):
    num = num + str(rn.randrange(0,9))

for i in range(2):
    stg = stg + ''.join(rn.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))

result = num+stg

print(result)
```

**Code 2 :** You can do it in one for loop as well

```
import random as rn

num = ''
stg = ''

for i in range(2):
    num = num + str(rn.randrange(0,9))
    stg = stg + ''.join(rn.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))

result = num+stg

print(result)
```

Incase any issue in code try to edit it